# Aurelia - if.bind doesn't work properly with select or radio button values

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I've the following html code

```
    <select value.bind="selectedA">
      <option repeat.for="optA of optionsA" value.bind="optA.name">${optA.name}</option>
    </select>
    <label repeat.for="optB of optionsB">
      <input type="radio" name="opt" model.bind="optB" checked.bind="selectedB"/>
      ${optB.name}
    </label>
```

Then I would like to show a container only if selectedA and selectedB are already defined.

```
    <section id="container" if.bind="selectedA && selectedB">
      container
    </section>
```

But the #container is never shown, even if the selectedA and selectedB are already defined. The only option to put this working is to print/use those values before the container div.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

selectedA and selectedB were not defined/initialised in .js file.